# Nodejs setNoDelay() not working . Is there an alternative to flush socket buffer?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm using this piece of code to send data to a Java application. I want to send multiple messages without closing the connection. The java app will wait and print each incoming message

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect(1010, 'localhost');
client.setNoDelay();
client.write("asdfdsfsdf");
client.write("jghjhgjhgj");
```

The problem is I won't receive 2 separate messages, but only 1. Furthermore, the data won't be even received by the Java app unless I call client.end(). 
How can I avoid closing the connection and flushing multiple messages ?

Answer (score -1):

Place a newline character at the end of your data.

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1010, 'localhost', function() {
    client.setNoDelay();
    client.write("asdfdsfsdf\n");
    client.write("jghjhgjhgj\n");
});
```

I experienced this same problem.  Adding the \n solved it for me.